# Why is `null` specifically required in recursive functions?

Tags: javascript

This function takes in an number and will attempt to find a sequence of +5 or *3 that will equal the original number. This function currently works in this state. But I noticed something odd. If you change return `null` to `return 'a string of something'` then the function will only return `'a string of something'`. Even if there is a solution and that solution satisfies the function. You can test this by just putting a string in where `null` is. My question, why does a recursive function require that `return` returns `null` instead of allowing you to return a string?

```
//$ write a function that, takes a given number, then tries to find a sequence of multiplication and addition, that produce the original number.

findSequence = ( n ) => {
  theMath = ( base, history ) => {
    if ( base == n ) {
      return history;
    } else if ( base > n ) {
      return null;
    } else {
      return theMath( base + 5, `(${history} + 5)`) || theMath( base * 3, `(${history} * 3)`);
    }
  }
  return theMath( 1, '1' );
}

console.log(findSequence(13));
```

Comment: It *doesn't* require it returns null, it needs to return something *falsey*, so an empty string `""` will work just fine.

Comment: The algorithm uses ``return theMath( base + 5, `(${history} + 5)`) ||``, so if the left-hand side evaluates to something truthy, the whole returned expression resolves to that truthy value, rather than going on to the right-hand side

Comment: Btw, [we've got a lot of topics](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=eloquent*+findsequence) that explain this very function in depth